# Routes in areas not working in MVC / Web forms hybrid app

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-routing

The app has four parts to it and 2 of them are in Areas like so (the solution is just one project fyi):

```
/Areas/ProjectA/...
/Areas/ProjectB/...
```

The models, views, and controllers for each are nested in there. The app with loclhost works fine and all the routes behave normally.

The routes do not work on the IIS server since the URL is like:

```
https://companywebsite.com/subfolder/
```

The subfolder for the project is messing with the routes.

The **Global.asax** file is like so:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("projecta/default.aspx"))
        {
            Context.Response.StatusCode = 301;
            Context.Response.Redirect("~/ProjectA/Home/Index");
        }

        if (Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("projectb/home.aspx"))
        {
            Context.Response.StatusCode = 301;
            Context.Response.Redirect("~/ProjectB/Home/Index");
        }
    }
```

Teh **RouteConfig.cs** file is like so:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.RouteExistingFiles = false;
        routes.IgnoreRoute("projectd/{*pathInfo}");

        // Register[Route] attributes
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapPageRoute(
            "WebFormDefault",
            string.Empty,
            "~/index.aspx");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

    }
```

This is the area registration for Project B:

```
public class ProjectBAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "ProjectB";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "ProjectB_home",
            "ProjectB/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
}
```

**Issues:**

1. https://loclahost:0123/ProjectA routes correctly but https://companywebsite.com/subfolder/ProjectA routes to https://companywebsite.com/ProjectA/Home/Index with a 404 error.
2. In ProjectB clicking on a link in htts://companywebsite.com/subfolder/ProjectB/Home/home/error?msg=Not%20Found instead of making an ajax call.

Comment: still need some help on this

Comment: Your redirects should be using `~/`, not `/`. Without the tilde, you are matching the root of the domain, not the app. That is why your see the 404 error.

Comment: ProjectA works great but ProjectB is still a mystery

Comment: added the area registration too

Comment: The companywebsite.com/subfolder/ProjectA works but not companywebsite.com/subfolder/ProjectB does not

Comment: Remove the `ProjectB_home` route. You don't need it.

Comment: That doesn't work locally. I have two home controllers one in each of the two areas

Comment: You shouldn't be adding routes to make something work locally. It sounds to me like your dev configuration needs to be reworked. Check this out: http://clontz.org/blog/2014/01/23/visual-studio-2012-setting-iis-express-to-host-site-at-subdirectory/