# MVC Area routing in a folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, routes, asp.net-routing

I have an MVC area app and it works fine locally:

```
https://localhost:8080/Area/Controller/View
```

But when I push to the server the routes get screwed up because the application is in a subfolder of the default web site like so:

```
https://companywebsite.com/Project/Area/Controller/View
```

Is there any way to fix this in web.config or IIS? I have a similar post at [Routes in areas not working in MVC / Web forms hybrid app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49928341/routes-in-areas-not-working-in-mvc-web-forms-hybrid-app).

Comment: Did you create an application in IIS for the `Project` folder?

Comment: Yes i did do that but sometimes it routes back to https://companywebsite.com/Area/Controller/View

Comment: Setting the application should tell MVC where to start routing from so that is not your problem. Do you have some sort of URL redirection running on this or the main company website?

Comment: i don't believe so. If you look at the linked post when I had only one area it worked fine. The second area is causing the issues. Works locally though.

Comment: So you DO have redirection going on...